# MYSQL : Find records between particular period

Tags: mysql, sql

I have one table named "checkInGuestUsers" in which there are columns like 'checkInTime(DATETIME), checkOutTime(DATETIME),rooms(varchar)

There is particular user who booked some rooms within particular time as,

```
UserId   checkInTime         checkOutTime              rooms

25     2014-12-04 00:00:00   2014-12-05 23:59:59       101,102
```

Now another user or same user wants to book the room within

```
"2014-12-03 00:00:00" to "2014-12-04 23:59:59" OR
"2014-12-04 00:00:00" to "2014-12-04 23:59:59"
```

then system should return all the room list except 101,102 as these rooms are already booked for 
"2014-12-04 00:00:00" to "2014-12-04 23:59:59"

I want a SQL query like if I select time from one of the above both then it will returns rooms which are booked within that period.

I have tried it with using between and greater than or less than conditions in SQL but failed to get exact result.

Answer (score 0):

select room_id from rooms where checkInTime is null or checkOutTime <= bookFrom and checkInTime is null or bookTo <= checkInTime

Is this homework?

Comment: Little late to ask after you've already given an answer to the question.

Comment: yeah, I never know if I should... mostly to shame them.  Does the site have a recommended policy?

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.* 
from rooms r
  left join checkInGuestUsers g 
  on g.rooms like r.<room_no>  -- actually not a good condition, should be improved
     and g.checkInTime <= {:book_to} and g.checkOutTime >= {:book_from}
where g.rooms is null
```